# Blender 2.8.2 Crashes on Startup (Windows10) - Not enough video memory?

Tags: error, windows, opengl

Update: Also tried 2.78 - It seemingly gets little bit further but still hungs up before accessing the program.

I just installed Blender 2.82a off the Windows64 installer on my brand new PC and it crashes upon starting. No error visible at all.

I had previously chosen to use the OpenGL renderer (figuring it would better suit my video card). I'd like to try choosing the DirectX one instead but I can no longer find where you are able to choose.

I also tried uninstalling and installing Blender 2.7 to no avail. Have also installed the latest Python just in case, but that was no good, either.

I did a debug memory dump on the cmd.exe and the results are below.

My system configuration is found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m80bionqd0qfipv/blender_system_info.txt?dl=0

A more detailed debug output is here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7ulibwgmgm2hlw/blender_debug_output.txt?dl=0

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Specs:

- Windows 10
- Intel Core I9-9900
- Asus rog strix b360-f
- Geforce RTX 2070 Super with latest Nvidia drivers (445.75)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.752]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Diego>"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\blender.exe" --debug-memory --debug-gpumem --debug-all > results.txt.
GPUTexture: texture alloc failed. Likely not enough Video Memory.
Current texture memory usage : 0.00 MiB.
GPUTexture: texture alloc failed. Likely not enough Video Memory.
Current texture memory usage : 0.00 MiB.
GPUTexture: texture alloc failed. Likely not enough Video Memory.
Current texture memory usage : 0.00 MiB.
I0407 23:31:42.917873 11880 blender_python.cpp:184] Debug flags initialized to:
CPU flags:
  AVX2       : True
  AVX        : True
  SSE4.1     : True
  SSE3       : True
  SSE2       : True
  BVH layout : BVH8
  Split      : False
CUDA flags:
  Adaptive Compile : False
OptiX flags:
  CUDA streams : 1
OpenCL flags:
  Device type    : ALL
  Debug          : False
  Memory limit   : 0
GPUTexture: texture alloc failed. Likely not enough Video Memory.
Current texture memory usage : 0.15 MiB.
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF66F0C7295
Module  : C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\blender.exe
```

Debug on Blender 2.7a is as follows:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.752]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Diego>"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" --debug-memory --debug-gpumem --debug-all > results.txt.
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
C:\b\blender\source\blender\gpu\intern\gpu_texture.c:655: `Pre Texture Unbind'' -> GL Error (0x0505 - GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY): Out of Memory
C:\b\blender\source\blender\gpu\intern\gpu_texture.c:655:`Pre Texture Unbind'' -> GL Error (0x0505 - GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY): Out of Memory

Comment: can you share a screen of your system configuration? for example: https://i.imgur.com/ASDFJmN.png

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access the Blender interface at all because of the crash, so I can't go into the Preferences menu. Is there anywhere else on Windows to find out the the same GPU system configuration details you are after?

Comment: I ran -debug GPU and here is the reported info. System Info (https://www.dropbox.com/s/m80bionqd0qfipv/blender_system_info.txt?dl=0=) Debug outoutput  (https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7ulibwgmgm2hlw/blender_debug_output.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out. I was connecting my display to the motherboard's HDMI port instead of my video card!

I couldn't access my Nvidia Display Properties as I "Didn't have an NVIDIA GPU attached to my display" so I suspected that was related, and when I fixed that, Blender also worked like a breeze. No wonder it couldn't properly find video memory, etc.